# Dynamic Slope Calculation on ArcGIS Online Web Application

Tags: raster, dem, arcgis-online, slope, arcgis-custom-widget

I have a DEM raster layer in our own GIS portal. It is then included in a web map online from which a web application is created.

I am looking for a way that would allow users to calculate slope by given two points on the web app. I can't find a widget in the web app builder that serves this purpose. I also tried the elevation profile service (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4aa7e7ae8b964ee88c78cc261b9faf82) but it didn't use my own DEM.

It also seems that none of the widgets in the web app builder works with a raster. Am I right?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Specifically - the sample uses a GP Service. Inside that service is a tool: Stack Profile. That tool plots the output elevation from a line based on a given DEM. So, yes, you can use your own raster, just not as direct as you're inferring. I have a GPK that has a model which does Stack Profile @ https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9eb7c69d9d124a488a76e2cf5fe401e9

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a simpler way to return slope value in a web app?

Comment: No. Maybe a custom JS app could get the elevation values out of an [ImageLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-ImageryLayer.html). Or maybe another technology like Google Earth Engine would support this. Either way, I think you're looking at a code/custom solution.